# Syntax error when calling one function from another

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I am trying to create a function which calls 2 other functions.

Below is the calling function's code from where I am trying to call 2 another functions, `schema1.func1()` and `schema1.func2()`.

But it is throwing error at the line `SELECT schema1.func1(temp_val);` saying:

> syntax error at or near "SELECT".

I tried to figure out the correct syntax but couldn't resolve.

I am using Postgres version 1.14.3

```
DECLARE 
  temp_val   int;
  cursor1 CURSOR
  FOR 
  SELECT col1 from schema1.table1;

BEGIN
  OPEN cursor1;
  LOOP
    FETCH cursor1 INTO temp_val;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
      SELECT CASE 
              WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT col2 FROM schema1.table2 WHERE col2 = temp_val) 
              THEN 
                BEGIN 
                SELECT schema1.func1(temp_val);
                SELECT schema1.func2(temp_val);
                END;
             END CASE;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor1;
END;
```

Comment: Can you post all your function definition, first lines miss ?

Comment: And please be more precise on the PostgreSQL server version 1.14.3 is not a valid version number, is it 9.6 or 10 or other one ?

Comment: did you put `begin` in `select case when then ` construct?.. `begin ..end;` is plpgsql - you cant use them in query

Comment: I think it might work if he would remove that first SELECT (before CASE) and change those 2 executing functions into PERFORM.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Thanks a lot! It worked.. I used PEFORM instead of SELECT for calling the functions and removed the SELECT before CASE.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `;` missing at:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT col2 FROM schema1.table2 WHERE col2 = temp_val)
```

so..

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT col2 FROM schema1.table2 WHERE col2 = temp_val);
```

Comment: It isn't that. What he did is this: `SELECT CASE WHEN condition THEN incorrect plpgsql code here END CASE;`. Adding semicolon after condition won't help.

Comment: my bad, I misread the case statement...  it won't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix PL/pgSQL `BEGIN ... END` blocks with SQL statement - even if that SQL statement is part of a PL/pgSQL function. So the `BEGIN` inside the `THEN` part of the `CASE` expression is invalid. A SQL `CASE` *expression*  ends with just an `END`. A PL/pgSQL `CASE` *statement* would end with `END CASE`. As you are trying to use a `CASE` expression, it would require just `END`, *not* `end case`.

You also need to use `perform` in order to call a function where you want to discard the result.

It's not clear to me what exactly you want to achieve. If you only want to call those two functions if a row does not exist in table2 then you can do this with a single loop:

```
DECLARE 
  t1_rec record;
BEGIN

  FOR t1_rec IN select t1.col1
                from table1 t1
                where not exists (select *
                                  from table2 t2
                                  where t2.col2 = t1.col1)
  LOOP
    perform schema1.func1(t1_rec.col1);
    perform schema1.func2(t1_rec.col1);
  END LOOP;
END;
```